# create a time limited page in drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal-6

I want to create a form in drupal 6 that user has force to fill the fields in a limited time (eg: 10 min).

I want to handle this limit time in the server side of my code.I don't want the user can change the time by change it's system clock.

Is it possible without $_SESSION ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [PHP session](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Something like this should work:

```
//Set your start time when the user enters the page:
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['start_time'])){
    $_SESSION['start_time'] = time();
}

//Check the current time against the start time when the user submits:
if(!isset($_SESSION['start_time'])){
    $elapsed = time() - $_SESSION['start_time'];
    $limit = 10*60; //Since time() is in seconds, multiply desired # of minutes by 60
    if($elapsed <= $limit){
        //It took less than 10 minutes
    }else{
        //It took more than 10 minutes
    }
}
```

Comment: if the user call my form and leave the form for long time without to submit or react it, How can i find the time overed(without java script)?

Comment: @Goodman It really depends. Is an account required to view this form, or can anyone do it? If the latter is true, there is no absolute way to know if they've visited the form before other than logged their IP in some type of database and checking for it when you load the form. (IPs are easily changed, though) If accounts are required, you could simply store the account name in a database upon the first time they load the form and check for it on subsequent loads.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. i have a form that anybody can use it,behind this form is a limited resource which my user in a competition condition should order it.i lock the few percent of resource during the time that user fill my form.I want nobody can lock this percent of resource for unlimited time.

Answer (score 1):

How about storing a time from when the user starts interacting with the form, and checking if the time has passed upon submission?

You can store the time for the specific user using sessions.

These are the references you need to do this:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php
http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php
```